# Any effect of MaxDirectMemorySize and sun.misc.unsafe

Tags: java, memory, operating-system, jvm

Now, this question arises mostly due to my misunderstanding of the native memory in JVM and probably stupid too. So a good easy to understand documentation in that direction would be nice.

Now I now that the sun.misc.unsafe class never recommended and the word "unsafe" itself implies. I also understand that it will be deprecated.

My understanding is that the MaxDirectMemorySize is to limit the native memory size that can be accessed by the lies of implementations of NIO or byte buffers. So is this memory size limit applied to memory regions that are created by the Unsafe class?

Also why this question is the thread stack growth is a native memory that is not in the control of the JVM. are there other ways within a java code that such native memory can be made to grow that is not in the hand or control of the VM.

These are some ponderings that I have for more of an understanding of the JVM that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is applied by maintaining a count of how much is used and comparing with the maximum memory size. You can find how this parameter is used in the JVM code.

Unless you do this as well, no maximum if being enforced.

> the thread stack growth is a native memory that is not in the control of the JVM.

The JVM doesn't implement this limit as it is performed by the OS. The JVM just sets it when the stack is created. C.f. `-Xss`

It's important to realise the JVM is a C program. It doesn't do anything magical and under the covers does the same things a C program would do.